# Access 2007 + SQL 2008: Bookmark operation stopped working

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Some code working for years suddenly started to produce unexpected (and false) results. The code runs in a form and is similar to this:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "docId = " & strContainsDocIdNumber
Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
```

This code normally brings the user to the correct record. and recently it started behaving erratically, going to totally unrelated records. e.g. instead of going to DocId 66345, it goes to DocId 1042 (always small numbers).
I did try to debug step by step, inspecting the values, no clue.
I also reindexed all tables in SQL Server 2008R2 database, and refreshed the table link, without any improvement.
Any hint or suggestion ?

edit: I solved the problem by using DoCmd.FindRecord, and I am quite sure my code is NOT in cause, since it worked for several years without a problem. I am looking for clues regarding Access - SQL Server interaction bugs like [this one](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-04.html).

Comment: when you debug, where is the problem?  does `strContainsDocIdNumber` have the value you expect? does the findfirst method take you to the expected record? is the rs.bookmark value valid and different from me.bookmark?

Comment: @Beth: I edited the question. The bug is that the display code is taking the user to record 1034 while variable strContainsDocIdNumber contains 66400, for example. Butthe code has ben working fine for 4 years, and is still working fine at another site !

Comment: are your sample figures exact? The difference looks so close to 65536 which would strongly imply some kind of overflow... Did you only recently got over 65k records?

Comment: @Unreason: the same code runs on another site, where they are now over  83000 for the DocId, without any problem. So it's not an Integer overflow issue. I really think about a db corruption...to be checked until I have th eopportunity to go there an revert to the old code from a new clean db.

Comment: I would suggest that one thing to try is to delete your ODBC linked tables and recreate them. If there have been any structural changes on the SQL Server tables/views, it can cause odd things to happen. I've never seen this type of thing, but if I did, that's one of the first things I'd do.

Comment: I just realised that since version 2002 you can directly use the form recordset ! `Me.Recordset.FindFirst "docId = " & strContainsDocIdNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered bugs in ms-access such as these in typical scenario

1. code works
2. code stops working without any changes to code
3. nothing helps

I usually try the following

- compact and repair
- decompile (read about it, this looked ok, http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/errors/Bad_DLL_Calling_Convention.asp)
- copy the object which contains the troublesome code into a new copy and delete the old one, rename the new one to old name. check if bug has gone away
- import all the objects into a freshly created new access database

Comment: I will give that a try. In those desperate cases, I generally create a blank db and import everything in it.

Comment: Btw, could you also check your version of DAO? Maybe somehow that got broken to some ancient version, for example the one that has this bug - http://support.microsoft.com/?id=238134#appliesto

Comment: thanks, I will check that as well. I will not be able to check before this week-end, but I will sure keep you updated here.